# Using preset event colors of google calendar in ContentValues

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Any way to use some of the preset colors provided by google calendar while creating events by configuring ContentValues.

[image]

I tried using

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put("eventColor", 0xffff3300);
```

But this changes back to default on click of the event

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color of the [event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) through the optional `colorId` property. To check the valid values of color, you can go to the [colors endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors#methods) and use [`get`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get) method to list all the available colors.

Also, you may also be interested to look from the [Android Open Source Project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/CalendarProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449743/android-create-custom-calendar-with-event).